# Installing the same App on the same FB Page more than once

Tags: facebook, installation

Is it possible to install and uninstall the same app on the same Facebook page more than once?

I have an app in development and installed it on my FB Page to test it. I uninstalled the app after the first round of testing but now want reinstall it to test the final version. I don't seem to be able to reinstall the app onto my FB Page. I am told that it's not possible to install & uninstall the same app multiple times on the same FB Page. Is this true? If it is then is there a workaround?

Comment: You can install/uninstall (aka add/remove) the App from your Fan Page as often as you like. What you can't do is adding a App's Tab to one page multiple times. Do you mean that?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, you can add or remove application on the page multiple times.

What do yout mean by *"uninstalled the app"* (uninstalled from Facebook Page or from your apps)?